# SSIS problem deploying package on SQL Server 2012

Tags: excel, ssis, sql-server-2012, etl

I want to ask what the problem may be. I run the ssis package on my computer, where I export data from Oracle to Excel and everything works. But when I deploy this package to my SQL Server 2012 machine, the package reports an error:

> Column "xx" cannot convert between unicode and non-unicode string data types.

My package looks like this:

[image]

It's very simple, and on my PC everything works.

I understand that if I probably add data conversion in the package, it will fix the error. But I'm more interested in why this is the case for me and not on the server?

Comment: I would suggest that *somewhere* you have an implicit conversion from unicode to non-unicode in your package. SSIS doesn't allow implicit conversions, you must be explicit. Either you need to ensure you keep things unicode the whole way through, or explicitly convert.

Comment: @Larnu But why does it work directly from my computer? But when I deploy it to a server, doesn't it work? That should be the same, right?

Comment: Not if the environments are different. Consult the logs in the SSISDB and see at which stage the error is happening, you'll then be able to trace that and work out exactly where the implicit conversion is happening.

Comment: @Larnu The error occurs during the last stage. But I don't get it. I select 4 columns from Oracle and insert them into Excel in DT_WSTR format. So I don't know why it reports an error with converting between non-unicode and unicode.

Answer (score 0):

The error occurred during the last stage, but I didn't get it. I selected 4 columns from Oracle and inserted them into Excel in DT_WSTR format, so I didn't know why it reported an error with converting between non-Unicode and Unicode. I resolved this error as follows:

```
ValidateExternalMetaData: False
```

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to explain how this solved the question, so that it is useful to other users with similar issues. Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem.